# How can I get a list of emails sent from a particular person?

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

I am using the Google Gmail API to get a list of messages. What I would like to do is get a list of all the messages that have been sent from a particular user. Here is what I have so far:

```
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2('', '', '');
oauth2Client.setCredentials(token);
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');

gmail.users.messages.list({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    userId: 'me'
}, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        cb(null, false);
    } else {
        cb(null, response);
    }
});
```

I tried setting `userId: 'person@email.com'` but that gave me the following error:

```
The API returned an error: Error: Delegation denied for person@email.com
```

What am I missing? Thanks ahead of time for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `q` parameter with value like this: `from:person@email.com`. It would filtrate emails by `from` header.
Then you are trying to use `userId: 'person@email.com` Google API thinks that you want a list of emails from `person@email.com` inbox (but you do not have access to it).